# group by pandas dataframe and select maximun value within sequence

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that represents elevation differences between points every 10 degrees for several target Turbines. I have selected the elevation differences that follow a criteria and I have added a column that represents if they are consecutive or not (metDegDiff = 10 represents consecutive points).

How can I select the maximum value of elevDif by targTurb in 3 or more consecutive 10 degree points?

```
ridgeDF2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'MetID':['A06_40','A06_50','A06_60','A06_70','A06_80','A06_100','A06_110','A06_140','A07_110','A07_130','A07_140','A08_100','A08_110','A08_120','A08_130','A08_220'],
    'targTurb':['A06','A06','A06','A06','A06','A06','A06','A06','A07','A07','A07','A08','A08','A08','A08','A08'],
    'metDeg':[30,50,60,70,80,100,110,140,110,130,140,100,110,120,130,220],
    'elevDif':[1.433234, 1.602997,3.227997,2.002991,2.414001,2.96402,1.513,1.793976,1.612,2.429993,1.639008,1.500977,3.048004,2.174011,1.813995,1.527008],
    'metDegDiff':[20,10,10,10,10,20,10,30,-30,20,10,-40,10,10,10,30]})
```

```
[Dbg]>>> ridgeDF2
      MetID targTurb  metDeg   elevDif  metDegDiff
0    A06_40      A06      30  1.433234          20
1    A06_50      A06      50  1.602997          10
2    A06_60      A06      60  3.227997          10
3    A06_70      A06      70  2.002991          10
4    A06_80      A06      80  2.414001          10
5   A06_100      A06     100  2.964020          20
6   A06_110      A06     110  1.513000          10
7   A06_140      A06     140  1.793976          30
8   A07_110      A07     110  1.612000         -30
9   A07_130      A07     130  2.429993          20
10  A07_140      A07     140  1.639008          10
11  A08_100      A08     100  1.500977         -40
12  A08_110      A08     110  3.048004          10
13  A08_120      A08     120  2.174011          10
14  A08_130      A08     130  1.813995          10
15  A08_220      A08     220  1.527008          30
```

In the example, for A06 there are 4 rows that have consecutive 10 metDeg values (rows 1, 2, 3, and 4) and for A8 there are 3 rows (rows 12, 13 and 14). Note that those 2 series have a length of 3 or more.

So, the output would be the maximum elevDif inside those two selected series. Like this:

```
MetID  targTurb  metDeg   elevDif  metDegDiff
A06_60      A06      60  3.227997          10
A08_110     A08     110  3.048004          10
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Please test it. Its faster and shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work. You can run each line separately to see what is happening.

```
ridgeDF2['t/f'] = ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'] != 10
ridgeDF2['t/f'] = ridgeDF2['t/f'].shift().fillna(0).cumsum()
ridgeDF2['count'] = ridgeDF2.groupby('t/f')['t/f'].transform(len)-1
ridgeDF2['count'] = np.where(ridgeDF2['count'] >= 3,True,False)
ridgeDF2.loc[ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'] != 10,'count'] = False
highest = ridgeDF2.loc[ridgeDF2['count'] == True]
highest = highest.loc[highest.groupby(['targTurb','metDegDiff','t/f'])['elevDif'].idxmax()]
highest.drop(columns = ['t/f','count'])
```

or

```
m = ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'].eq(10).diff().ne(0).cumsum()
ridgeDF2.loc[ridgeDF2.groupby(m).transform('size').ge(3) & ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'].eq(10)].sort_values('elevDif',ascending=False).groupby(m).head(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Chained solution**

```
   ridgeDF2.loc[ridgeDF2[((ridgeDF2.assign(group=(ridgeDF2.metDegDiff!=10).cumsum())).groupby('group')['metDegDiff'].transform(lambda x: (x==10)& (x.count()>=3)))].groupby('targTurb')['elevDif'].idxmax()]
```

**Step by step solution**

`.cumsum()` `metDegDiff` to create groups where the first element is not 10.

```
ridgeDF2=ridgeDF2.assign(group=(ridgeDF2.metDegDiff!=10).cumsum())
```

Apply multiple filter to get rid of `metDegDiff` not equal to 10 in groups generated above and to retain groups where count of consecutive values=10 is equal or more than 3. I chain `groupby()` ,`.transform()` and boolean selection to a achieve this

```
g=ridgeDF2[ridgeDF2.groupby('group')['metDegDiff'].transform(lambda x: (x==10)& (x.count()>=3))]
```

From what remains above, select indexes with maximum values

```
g.loc[g.groupby('targTurb')['elevDif'].idxmax()]
```

Outcome

```
  MetID targTurb  metDeg   elevDif  metDegDiff
2    A06_60      A06      60  3.227997          10
12  A08_110      A08     110  3.048004          10
```

Timing

```
%timeit ridgeDF2.loc[ridgeDF2[((ridgeDF2.assign(group=(ridgeDF2.metDegDiff!=10).cumsum())).groupby('group')['metDegDiff'].transform(lambda x: (x==10)& (x.count()>=3)))].groupby('targTurb')['elevDif'].idxmax()]
9.01 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This code will work if the 10 values do not have to be next to each other. The question is, do the 3 or more consecutive values have to be consecutive themselves? For example, if index 6 is at 4.513 instead of 1.513 it would get returned.

Comment: Right, but the question is if the 10's need to be consecutive. The first groupby would include indexes `[1,2,3,4,6]`, but if the 10's need to be consecutive themselves, only indexes `[1,2,3,4]` should be included in the first group.

Comment: @user13802115 Thanks, your comment do not now apply. My answer is also much faster

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a group column for the same consecutive value in metDegDiff and same targTurb, using `shift` and `cumsum`. Then you can use this group column to select where the group has more or equal (`ge`) 3 values obtained by `map` the group number with the `value_counts` of the group number, and where the value in metDegDiff is equal (`eq`) to 10. Now that you have only the groups of interest, you can `sort_values` on elevDif and `drop_duplicates` on the group column to keep the maximum value per group. You end with `drop` the column gr and `sort_values` per targTurb if necessary.

```
ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'] = ridgeDF2['metDeg'].diff() #I assume calculated this way

#create a group number with same consecutive values and same targTurb
ridgeDF2['gr'] = (ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'].ne(ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'].shift())
                  |(ridgeDF2['targTurb'].ne(ridgeDF2['targTurb'].shift()))
                 ).cumsum()

#get the result dataframe
res_ = (ridgeDF2.loc[ridgeDF2['metDegDiff'].eq(10) #row with 10 in metDegDiff
                     &ridgeDF2['gr'].map(ridgeDF2['gr'].value_counts()).ge(3)] #and row with group of greater equal 3 values
                .sort_values(by='elevDif') # ascending sort of the elevDif
                .drop_duplicates('gr', keep='last') #keep the last row pergroup having higher number
                .drop('gr', axis=1) #remove the extra group column
                .sort_values('targTurb') #if you need
       )
```

and you get the rows you want

```
print (res_)
      MetID targTurb  metDeg   elevDif  metDegDiff
2    A06_60      A06      60  3.227997        10.0
12  A08_110      A08     110  3.048004        10.0
```